Issue implementing ArrayLists in Java Game
I am having an issue in my java game were I can move my character fine with W,A,S,D keys, but only one animation sprite shows up and moves around the screen. I am unsure if the issue is because I populated the sprites incorrectly or because I rendered them incorrectly.
I have a total of 16 sprites and my goal is to move my character around the screen with the animations for the W,A,S and D directions. I attempted to  use 4 different arrayLists to split the sprites up and have those animations move to the corresponding 'W', 'A', 'S' and 'D' keys. The issue with that is that I had 4 different sprites splitting off into their respective directions rather than having one fluid animated motion. To try and solve this, I tried commenting out the other ArrayLists and only used one. The result of this is that I have one animation sprite moving around, but its a singular sprite moving in all directions.  I have attached my main.java file below for review.
package Main;

import java.awt.Color;
//import java.awt.RenderingHints.Key;
//import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
//import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import Data.Vector2D;
import Data.spriteInfo;
import logic.Control;
import timer.stopWatchX;

public class Main{
    // Fields (Static) below...
    public static Color c = new Color(0,153,0);
    public static Vector2D currentVec = new Vector2D(-100, -100);
    public static boolean isImageDrawn = false;
    public static stopWatchX timer = new stopWatchX(250);
    public static ArrayList<spriteInfo> move = new ArrayList<>(); 
    //public static ArrayList<spriteInfo> up = new ArrayList<>();
    //public static ArrayList<spriteInfo> down = new ArrayList<>();
    //public static ArrayList<spriteInfo> left = new ArrayList<>();
    public static int currentSpriteIndex = 0;
    
    
    public static void pressW() {
        //retrieve the current SpriteInfo Object
        spriteInfo currentSprite = move.get(currentSpriteIndex);
        //Vector2D  currentPosition = up.getCoords();
        //get the current position of the sprite
        Vector2D  currentPosition = currentSprite.getCoords();
        //calculate the new position by decrementing the y coordinate by 10, allows it to go in the up direction
        Vector2D newPosition = new Vector2D(currentPosition.getX(), currentPosition.getY()-10);
        //updates sprites current position with new position
        currentSprite.setCoords(newPosition);
    
    }
    public static void pressS() {
        spriteInfo presentSprite = move.get(currentSpriteIndex);
        
        Vector2D presentPosition = presentSprite.getCoords();
        
        Vector2D newnewPosition = new Vector2D(presentPosition.getX(), presentPosition.getY()+10);
        
        presentSprite.setCoords(newnewPosition);
        
        
    }
    public static void pressA() {
        spriteInfo nowSprite = move.get(currentSpriteIndex);
        
        Vector2D nowPosition = nowSprite.getCoords();
        
        Vector2D brandnewPosition = new Vector2D(nowPosition.getX()-10, nowPosition.getY());
        
        nowSprite.setCoords(brandnewPosition);
        
    }
    
    public static void pressD() {
        spriteInfo nownowSprite = move.get(currentSpriteIndex);
        
        Vector2D nownowPosition = nownowSprite.getCoords();
        
        Vector2D recentPosition = new Vector2D(nownowPosition.getX()+10, nownowPosition.getY()); 
        
        nownowSprite.setCoords(recentPosition);
        
    }
    
    // End Static fields...
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Control ctrl = new Control();               
        ctrl.gameLoop();                            
    }
    
     
    public static void start(){
        //  Populate sprites, total of 16 split into 4 arrayLists
        
        
        
        spriteInfo right1 = new spriteInfo(new Vector2D(0,150), "sprite1");
        spriteInfo right2 = new spriteInfo(new Vector2D(1,150), "sprite2");
        spriteInfo right3 = new spriteInfo(new Vector2D(2,150), "sprite3");
        spriteInfo right4 = new spriteInfo(new Vector2D(3,150), "sprite4");
        
        spriteInfo left1 = new spriteInfo(new Vector2D(4,150), "sprite5");
        spriteInfo left2= new spriteInfo(new Vector2D(5,150), "sprite6");
        spriteInfo left3 = new spriteInfo(new Vector2D(6,150), "sprite7");
        spriteInfo left4 = new spriteInfo(new Vector2D(7,150), "sprite8");
        
        spriteInfo up1 = new spriteInfo(new Vector2D(8,150), "sprite9");
        spriteInfo up2 = new spriteInfo(new Vector2D(9,150), "sprite10");
        spriteInfo up3 = new spriteInfo(new Vector2D(10,150), "sprite11");
        spriteInfo up4 = new spriteInfo(new Vector2D(11,150), "sprite12");
        
        spriteInfo down1 = new spriteInfo(new Vector2D(12,150), "sprite13");
        spriteInfo down2 = new spriteInfo(new Vector2D(13,150), "sprite14");
        spriteInfo down3 = new spriteInfo(new Vector2D(14,150), "sprite15");
        spriteInfo down4 = new spriteInfo(new Vector2D(15,150), "sprite16");
        
        move.add(right1); //add to "right" arrayList 
        move.add(right2);
        move.add(right3);
        move.add(right4);
        
        move.add(left1); //add to "left" arrayList
        move.add(left2);
        move.add(left3);
        move.add(left4);
        
        move.add(up1); //add to "up" arrayList
        move.add(up2);
        move.add(up3);
        move.add(up4);
        
        move.add(down1); //add to "down" arrayList
        move.add(down2);
        move.add(down3);
        move.add(down4);
        }
    
     
    public static void update(Control ctrl) {
        
        
        //check for key presses and then update sprite positions
//      
        //Render Sprites to display
        
        for (spriteInfo d : move) {
            ctrl.addSpriteToFrontBuffer(d.getCoords().getX(), d.getCoords().getY(), d.getTag());
        }
        for (spriteInfo a : move) {
            ctrl.addSpriteToFrontBuffer(a.getCoords().getX(), a.getCoords().getY(), a.getTag());
        }
        for (spriteInfo w : move) {
            ctrl.addSpriteToFrontBuffer(w.getCoords().getX(), w.getCoords().getY(), w.getTag());
        }
        for (spriteInfo s : move) {
            ctrl.addSpriteToFrontBuffer(s.getCoords().getX(), s.getCoords().getY(), s.getTag());
        }
        
        
                }
    
    
}


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

What is a sprite? "//  Populate sprites, total of 16 split into 4 arrayLists" There is only one arraylist. If I think of a sprite as being a single frame of an animation. Then you would need to update which sprite is being displayed. " I am unsure if the issue is because I populated the sprites incorrectly or because I rendered them incorrectly." You aren't showing us the code that does either. I think these are the correct questions, but we cannot help you with the info provided.
